# Use a Mantel test in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices, which are exactly the same ones. I apply a mantel test and I get this output :

```
> mantel.rtest(p.dist, cor.dist, nrepet=99)
Monte-Carlo test
Call: mantel.rtest(m1 = p.dist, m2 = cor.dist, nrepet = 99)

Observation: 1 

Based on 99 replicates
Simulated p-value: 0.01 
Alternative hypothesis: greater 

     Std.Obs  Expectation     Variance 
4.994451e+02 2.074923e-04 4.007229e-06
```

Does that mean they are the same ones or not?

Thanks

Comment: It means they are the same ones. Check <https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-perform-a-mantel-test-in-r/>

Comment: Did you consider using `?mantel.rtest` to see what the documentation says about the function and its output?